Supabase querying by email in Flask application using supabase_py
Querying Supabase 'users' table with the 'email' column returns empty data, but changing the value of the column as well as the value to match it to, into a normal text and not a email format such as 'johndoe@mail.com' works.
supabase table
query in python
result in terminal
I tried changing the values into normal text format, random strings, and that worked when querying, but once I enter text in email format into the supabase table and try to query with the exact same values that I copied and pasted, it does not work.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
